# Table 'add', 'editable' before, and after 'append'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this table data that gets appended; however, I want to make it where you can add the table data using 'text' input type and make the table data 'editable' before and after the table data gets appended.

The thing is the append overwrites the previous data/values I added before. I believe it's doing this because the table get populated at dom ready?

I want to make it similar to the code snippet, but it's not doing that.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
var arr1 = generateItem();
if (arr1) {
    var arr2 = [].concat(arr1);
    var tr;
    $.each(arr2, function (i, e) {
        tr = $('<tr>');
        tr.append("<td>" + "<button id='modalBtn" + i + "' type='button' class='btn btn-info' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>Info</button>" +
     "<button id='editBtn" + i + "' type='button' class='btn btn-default editBtn' data-target='#editBtn'>Edit</button>" + 
          "<button id='delete" + i + "' type='button' class='btn btn-danger deleteBtn' data-target='#deleteBtn' style='width:50px'>X</button>" + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + (e.Name || "") + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + (e.Email || "") + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + (e.Phone || "") + "</td>");
        $('#parentTableBody').append(tr);

        populateSchoolInfo(i, e);
    });
}
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var idx = $(e.relatedTarget).closest('tr').index();
    $('#schoolModalBody tr').hide().filter('[studentidx=' + idx + ']').show();
});
    $('.editBtn').on('click', function () {
            var currentTD = $(this).parents('tr').find('td');
            if ($(this).html() == 'Edit') {
                currentTD = $(this).parents('tr').find('td');
                $.each(currentTD, function () {
                    $(this).prop('contenteditable', true)
                });
            } else {
                $.each(currentTD, function () {
                    $(this).prop('contenteditable', false)
                });
            }
            
                        $(this).html($(this).html() == 'Edit' ? 'Save' : 'Edit')

        });
        
        $('.deleteBtn').on('click', function () {
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
            return false;
            });
 $("#addBtn").click(function () {
     $("#parentTable").each(function () {
         var tds = '<tr>';
         jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function () {
             tds += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
         });
         tds += '</tr>';
         if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
             $('tbody', this).append(tds);
         } else {
             $(this).append(tds);
         }
     });
});

            
});

function populateSchoolInfo(idx, kid) {
var tr;
$.each(kid.Edu, function (j, v) {
    tr = $('<tr>', {studentidx: idx});
    tr.append("<td>" + (v.School || "") + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + (v.Grade || "") + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + (v.Job || "") + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + (v.Martial || "") + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + (v.ETC || "") + "</td>");
    $('#schoolModalBody').append(tr);
    
});
}

function generateItem() {
var kids = [{
    Name: "Gina",
    Email: "gina@email.com",
    Phone: "211-456-1234",
    Edu: [{School: "college", Grade: "Freshmen", Job: "Student", Martial: "S", ETC: " "},
        {School: "college2", Grade: "Freshmen2", Job: "Student2", Martial: "S2", ETC: "2"},
        {School: "college3", Grade: "Freshmen3", Job: "Student3", Martial: "S3", ETC: "3"}]
    },
    {
        Name: "Mark",
        Email: "mark@email.com",
        Phone: "144-411-2312",
        Edu: [{School: "highschool", Grade: "senior", Job: "cashier", Martial: "S", ETC: "honors"}]
    },
    {
        Name: "Jake",
        Email: "jake@email.com",
        Phone: "333-211-1111",
        Edu: [{School: "highschool", Grade: "senior", Job: "cashier", Martial: "S", ETC: "honors"}]
    }
];
return kids;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="parentTable">
    <thead>
    <tr class="category">
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
                        
    <tbody id="parentTableBody">
<td><button id='addBtn' type='button' class='btn btn-success' data-target='#addRow'>Add Row</button></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="name"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="phone"></td>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h3>Info</h3>

                <div class="well well-sm overflow-auto">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed" id="schoolTable">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>School</th>
                            <th>Grade</th>
                            <th>Job</th>
                            <th>Martial</th>
                            <th>Etc</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="schoolModalBody">
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no need to link to Fiddles. Just click the "Code Snippet" icon in the new question toolbar and insert your code there.

Comment: Thank you Scott; I will make sure to do that next time. I removed the sentence regarding the Fiddle as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's the thing -- why are you creating an entirely different mechanism for adding a row, versus your initial population of the table? Functionally, it is exactly the same.

If you look at your addRow handler, you don't actually get the data from the inputs -- you simply seem to clone things around.

How about if we were to pull the logic that creates the HTML DOM fragment that will be a table row out into its own function, called createRow()? That can expect an index and an object, and use them to populate the cells of the row. Then we can simply append that row into the end of the #parentTableBody, and add that object to the school collection, exactly as you have done.

The beauty of pulling that code out into its own function is, when you create a new student, you use exactly the same function! You'll create the index, and the student object, but then you'll call createRow(), you'll append that row, and you'll add the new student record to the school. Nothing's being cloned or re-appended -- it's simply doing the same thing its always done.

Here's how I refactored your code with the above suggestion, and also commented all to heck. I am a firm believer in commenting, and using console.log or some sort of debugger!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // create the original collection of student records.
  let arr1 = generateItem();
  if (arr1) {
    // clone that collection into a second array (?)
    let arr2 = [...arr1];
    // For each member of the student collection, create a table row.
    $.each(arr2, function(index, element) {
      // createRow() creates the DOM student row.
      let myRow = createRow(index, element);
      // Stick that row we just created into the parent table.
      $('#parentTableBody').append(myRow);
      // Add that student into the actual school info.
      populateSchoolInfo(index, element);
    });
  }

  $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var idx = $(e.relatedTarget).closest('tr').index();
    $('#schoolModalBody tr').hide().filter('[studentidx=' + idx + ']').show();
  });
  $("#parentTableBody").on('click', '.editBtn', function() {
    var currentTD = $(this).parents('tr').find('td');
    if ($(this).html() == 'Edit') {
      currentTD = $(this).parents('tr').find('td');
      $.each(currentTD, function() {
        $(this).prop('contenteditable', true)
      });
    } else {
      $.each(currentTD, function() {
        $(this).prop('contenteditable', false)
      });
    }

    $(this).html($(this).html() == 'Edit' ? 'Save' : 'Edit')

  });

  $("#parentTableBody").on('click', '.deleteBtn', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    return false;
  });
  /****
   * When the add button is clicked, we first create a new Student object.
   *  By doing this, we can then re-use the same createRow function we
   *  used when we created each initial row, thus ensuring the same result.
   ****/
  $("#addBtn").click(function() {
    // Get all the text input fields for this form.
    let inputs = $(this).parent().siblings().find("input[type='text']");
    // Create an empty student object.
    let myStudentObj = {};
    // Iterate over all the text inputs, and create properties for the student
    //  Each text input name will become the property name.
    inputs.each(function(index, input){
      /***
       * This is a complicated conversion: as the createRow has been defined to
       *  expect a Titlecase property (first letter is capitalized), but the input
       *  names are lower case, we need to retrieve the input name, convert it
       *  to all lowercase (just to be safe), then convert the first char to upper.
       ***/
      let propName = $(input).prop("name")
                             .toLowerCase();
      propName = propName.replace(propName[0], propName[0].toUpperCase());
      // Now, create a property on the object with the proper value.
      myStudentObj[propName] = $(input).val();
      // And let's also blank that input field, so we can create a new student easily.
      $(input).val("");
    });
    
    /***
     * A little more funkiness: the index is the object's position in an array, or list.
     *   As we have been adding the records sequentially, the number of rows is the index
     *   of the last row. Adding one to that will give us the index of the current student.
     ***/
    let myStudentIndex = $("#parentTableBody tr.student-row").length,
        
    // And we can create that DOM fragment, as we did when we initialized the list above.
        myRow = createRow(myStudentIndex, myStudentObj);
    // add our newly created DOM fragment to the parent container.
    $("#parentTableBody").append(myRow);
    
    // Add the student to the school collection itself.
    populateSchoolInfo(myStudentIndex, myStudentObj)
    

  });


});

function populateSchoolInfo(idx, kid) {
  var tr;
  $.each(kid.Edu, function(j, v) {
    tr = $('<tr>', {
      studentidx: idx
    });
    tr.append("<td>" + (v.School || "") + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + (v.Grade || "") + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + (v.Job || "") + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + (v.Martial || "") + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + (v.ETC || "") + "</td>");
    $('#schoolModalBody').append(tr);

  });
}

function generateItem() {
  var kids = [{
      Name: "Gina",
      Email: "gina@email.com",
      Phone: "211-456-1234",
      Edu: [{
          School: "college",
          Grade: "Freshmen",
          Job: "Student",
          Martial: "S",
          ETC: " "
        },
        {
          School: "college2",
          Grade: "Freshmen2",
          Job: "Student2",
          Martial: "S2",
          ETC: "2"
        },
        {
          School: "college3",
          Grade: "Freshmen3",
          Job: "Student3",
          Martial: "S3",
          ETC: "3"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      Name: "Mark",
      Email: "mark@email.com",
      Phone: "144-411-2312",
      Edu: [{
        School: "highschool",
        Grade: "senior",
        Job: "cashier",
        Martial: "S",
        ETC: "honors"
      }]
    },
    {
      Name: "Jake",
      Email: "jake@email.com",
      Phone: "333-211-1111",
      Edu: [{
        School: "highschool",
        Grade: "senior",
        Job: "cashier",
        Martial: "S",
        ETC: "honors"
      }]
    }
  ];
  return kids;
}
/****
* createRow() -- create the student row DOM fragment.
* index = the student index
* obj = the student object, formatted like:
* obj = { Name: "name", Email: "email", Phone: "555-555-5555", <other optional fields>}
*
* returns a td DOM node containing the student info.
****/
function createRow(index, obj) {
  // console.log(obj);
  tr = $('<tr class="student-row">');
  tr.append("<td>" + "<button id='modalBtn" + index + "' type='button' class='btn btn-info' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>Info</button>" +
    "<button id='editBtn" + index + "' type='button' class='btn btn-default editBtn' data-target='#editBtn'>Edit</button>" +
    "<button id='delete" + index + "' type='button' class='btn btn-danger deleteBtn' data-target='#deleteBtn' style='width:50px'>X</button>" + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td>" + (obj.Name || "") + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td>" + (obj.Email || "") + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td>" + (obj.Phone || "") + "</td>");

  return tr;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<table id="parentTable">
  <thead>
    <tr class="category">
      <th></th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="parentTableBody">
    <td><button id='addBtn' type='button' class='btn btn-success' data-target='#addRow'>Add Row</button></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="name"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="phone"></td>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h3>Info</h3>

        <div class="well well-sm overflow-auto">
          <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed" id="schoolTable">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>School</th>
                <th>Grade</th>
                <th>Job</th>
                <th>Martial</th>
                <th>Etc</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="schoolModalBody">
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that this has NO validity checking or whatever, it simply accepts any values for those three fields and creates that student object. Validation's a whole 'NOTHER conversation.

Comment: Thank you! By pulling the logic into its own function, it resolved the problem. Not only that, it made my previous code more clean. Also, thank you for your thorough comments as well; it really helped me understand the code as I read them!

Comment: And that is exactly why I comment so extensively. Not only does it help other developers when they come along later and review my code, it occasionally helps me to catch possible bugs or gotchas -- a comment that says to expect one behaviour and a block of code that does something else is a good sign something's amiss.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('.editBtn').on('click', function () {...
```

This code adds an event listener when executed, every DOM element added AFTER won't fire anything.

To get things working you must listen to the event on `document` and then to the element you desire:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.editBtn', function () {...
```

Comment: Good catch, Leonardo, and I edited this in my post. But that isn't really what the OP was asking about. If I get the question, when you click the 'Add' button, which does exist as a static element before the dynamic DOM nodes are created, isn't creating the NEW student record. Rather, it seems to be cloning an existing one.